# libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll не найден

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks

Я собрал проект на Code::blocks ,  Но он запускается только через само IDE при попытке запустить вне IDE пишет

> Не удается обнаружить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдите этот файл в папке, где установлена среда программирования/компилятор, и скопируйте в папку, где лежит ваш исполняемый файл.

Либо можно заморочиться со статической компоновкой.