# Запихивание всех dll в один exe-файл

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, dll, exe, линковка

Написал игру "*snake*" в Code::Blocks 20.03. exe-шник так просто не запускается - нужны dll. Но я хочу, чтобы эта программа была легко передаваемым единым exe-файлом. Я слышал про статичную линковку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно упихнуть все dll в **один exe-файл**. По возможности без VisualStudio (нет возможности скачать). Спасибо.
P. S. В вопросе линковки я **чайник**. Даже не знаю что это такое (просто отрывочно видел на др. форумах, так ничего не поняв).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [libgcc\_s\_dw2-1.dll не найден](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724268/libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Comment: Найти эту dll в папке с компилятором и положить рядом с экзешником. Это нормально.

Comment: Хорошо. Это работает. Спасибо. Но как это всё кинуть в один (.exe) файл? Я использую code::blocks. Заранее Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите упихнуть все dll в exe

Comment: Во флаги линковщика допишите `-static`.

Comment: Пишите `@username` в начале комментариев когда отвечаете, а то нам не приходят уведомления.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо большое. Помогло. Только (я нуб в stack oerflow) я не могу понять как на Андромеда выделить ответ...:(

Comment: Андромеда? Он должен быть оформлен как ответ (а не комментарий), чтобы рядом с ответом можно было нажать галочку. Сейчас сделаю ответ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо. Дурацкий Т9. Я писал с андроид устройства. Мне "андроиде" исправили на "Андромеда".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во флаги линковщика нужно дописать `-static`.